# Division of very big numbers using arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to make a calculator for very big numbers (even bigger than long long) and I'm using arrays to make it work.

So far I have done addition, subtraction and multiplication. But I'm really stuck in division part.

**EDIT:
new progress. as a friend mentioned i need to compare result array with divisor each time so i can stop the progress any time divisor is larger than dividend. I managed to make a nice function to compare it every time. this function is tested separately and it's working fine. OK. now i'm starting to make REAL progress. i got the quotient. now i will try to put quotient in array so that we can work with LARGER numbers!**

```
    #define MAX_SIZE 50
    #define SIZE_USE (MAX_SIZE-1)

    int div(int inum_first[], int inum_second[], int div_result[], int firstlen, int secondlen)
{
    int i;
    int check1 = 0, check2 = 0;

    int zeroC = 0;

    int tmp[MAX_SIZE];

    for (i = 0; i <= SIZE_USE; i++)
    {
        tmp[i] = 0;
    }

    int inum_firstCP[MAX_SIZE] = { 0 };

    for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
    {
        inum_firstCP[i] = inum_first[i]; // create a copy of inum_first
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= SIZE_USE; i++)
    {
        if (inum_first[i] != 0)
            check1++;

        if (inum_second[i] != 0)
            check2++;
    }

    if (secondlen > firstlen)
    {
        zeroC++;
        goto EOI;
    }

    if (check2 == 0)
    {
        puts("\nExpected error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int j = 0, p = 0;

    int s = 0;
    int o = 1; // o is Quotient!

    do
    {
        for (i = SIZE_USE; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (tmp[i] = inum_firstCP[i] - inum_second[i] >= 0)
            {
                tmp[i] = inum_firstCP[i] - inum_second[i];
            }
            else
            {
                inum_firstCP[i - 1] = inum_firstCP[i - 1] - 1;
                tmp[i] = (inum_firstCP[i] + 10) - inum_second[i];
            }

            inum_firstCP[i] = tmp[i];

        }
    if (compare(inum_firstCP, inum_second, firstlen, secondlen) < 0) break;
    j++;
    o++;
    } while (j<MAX_SIZE); // anything else will also work

EOI:

    return 0;
}

int compare(int inum_firstCP[], int inum_second[], int firstlen, int secondlen)
{
    int c = 0, d = 0;
    int i;

    firstlen = MAX_SIZE, secondlen = MAX_SIZE; // temporary. will provide a better solution ASAP
    if (firstlen > secondlen)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (secondlen > firstlen)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < firstlen; i++)
        {
            if (inum_firstCP[i] > inum_second[i]) c++;
            else if (inum_second[i] > inum_firstCP[i]) d++;
        }
        if (c>d) return 1;
        else if (d>c) return -1;
    }

    return 0; // else
}
```

Comment: Why not use https://gmplib.org/? It's the GNU MP Bignum library, it already does big numbers. There is an example at https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-discuss/2008-March/003085.html

Comment: I shouldn't really use an external library...

Comment: @sashoalm I think he want to learn how to do it himself.

Comment: @FUZxxl Then why does he ask someone else to code it? If he'll look at someone else's code anyway, GNU MP is opensource, he can look at that.

Comment: @sashoalm GMP is horribly complicated, it's not a good project to learn from.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579495/division-of-a-big-number-of-100-digits-stored-as-string

Comment: @sashoalm how does this help??

Comment: There are various algorithms for long division, some of which are better in certain cases. For example, dividing a multi-word number by a single word number can be done more efficiently with one algorithm, while dividing by a multi-word number is better with a different algorithm. There's plenty of documentation for various algorithms available with some simple searches...

Comment: "I'm really stuck in division part." is vague.  What do you want - a whole solution?

Comment: @chux for division, yes.

Comment: The wikipedia page contained an interesting link [**Fast Division of Large Integers: A Comparison of Algorithms**](http://www.treskal.com/kalle/exjobb/original-report.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

If you have the subtraction of those big numbers the easiest solution is to take the two numbers and substract one from the other until you are left with something less then zero. It is the basic solution, it works but is a bit slow.

To make it faster you can do the following, take the divisor, multiply it by 2, if it is less then the dividend, keep on multiplying. When you will reach the first number bigger then a dividend set the corresponding bit to 1, subtract the multiplied dividend then do the same for the result.
There is the same thing nicely described on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm).

In order to make it work you need to implement your own comparing function.
Assuming you will store the size of the malloc allocation in your structure in filed len you can do something like this:

```
int compare( mynum &a, mynum &b){
  if (a.len() > b.len()){
     return 1;
  } else (if b.len() > a.len()){
   return -1;
  } else(){
    for(int i = b.len(); i > 0; i--){
      if (a[i] > b[i]){
        return 1;
      } else if(b[i] > a[i]){
        return -1;
      }
     }
   #if we get there the numbers are the same
   return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: A very good idea but how to make computer detect if divisor is bigger than dividend so that we could stop...

Comment: You will need to write your own comparison. First compare which array is longer, if they are the same take first- leftmost number, then go to the right.

Comment: It will be hard to do without knowing your code (for the code you have posted it is fairly simple but it is not using variable length arrays with big numbers). I don't want to be rude but now that you have idea how to code it from the algorithm point of view, I don't want to be coding your homework for you.

Comment: As i said, I'm working on a complete calculator and i'm using Visual C++ (although using C code) so I can't use VLA. however i used malloc in my Multiplication function..

Comment: what is mynum &a?? first integer array?? also there is no .len because it's C. I also added my function . it uses subtraction. it's not enough though.

Comment: you must create your own structure which will be  named mynum having two fields, one is length of your array and second is your array the other method is to have the guardian value and instead of .len using other function which would calculate length

Comment: I'll work on that but in the mean time what do you think of my function?? anyway to make it work??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76463/discussion-between-cerkiewny-and-vvvsg).

Comment: I think "a bit slow" is a bit understated... Division by repeated subtraction is probably the least useful algorithm out there, especially the larger the numbers get. For example, dividing a 1024-decimal-digit integer by a 10-decimal-digit integer, might have you waiting until the eventual collapse and heat death of the universe for your first result (`O(10^1014)` subtraction operations)... There are much more efficient algorithms out there...

Comment: I gave the faster alternative as well, and the OP seems as person who is learning programming so IMHO he should start small and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this before and was very happy to implement it the same way as you'd do it by hand, with a small modification of multiple subtraction at each step. The algorithm is like that:

1. Multiply divisor by ten as often as you can without divisor becoming bigger than dividend.
2. Subtract divisor from dividend as often as you can and remember how many times.
3. The rest of all the subtractions is the new dividend.
4. Repeat at step (1) until dividend is smaller than divisor.
5. The current dividend is the "rest".
6. All the numbers remembered at step (3) are the "result" when ordered left to right (left calculated first).

Okay, let's try it by example:

E.g. you have 25391 and want to divide it by 71.

```
(1) 25391 and 71 * 10 = 710
    25391 and 710 * 10 = 7100
    25391 and 7100 * 10 = 71000 <-- TOO BIG
(2) 25391 - 7100 => X
    18291 - 7100 => X
    11191 - 7100 => X
     4091 - 7100 <--- NOT POSSIBLE
(3) Number of X: 3
(4) 4091 > 71, okay, back to step 1.

(1) 4091 and 71 * 10 = 710
    4091 and 710 * 10 = 7100 <--- TOO BIG
(2) 4091 - 710 => X
    3381 - 710 => X
    2671 - 710 => X
    1961 - 710 => X
    1251 - 710 => X
     541 - 710 <--- NOT POSSIBLE
(3) Number of X: 5
(4) 541 > 71, okay, back to step 1

(1) 541 and 71 * 10 = 710 <--- TOO BIG
(2) 541 - 71 => X
    470 - 71 => X
    399 - 71 => X
    328 - 71 => X
    257 - 71 => X
    186 - 71 => X
    115 - 71 => X
     44 - 71 <--- NOT POSSIBLE
(3) Number of X: 7
(4) 44 > 71, WRONG, continue with step 5
(5) Rest is 44
(6) Result is 357
```

If you had just tested how often you can subtract 71 from 25391, this loop would have had **357 iterations!** Of course, my solution uses multiplication, but honestly, multiplying by 10 is no real multiplication, *just shift all digits one position to the left and put a zero at the top right one.*

The algorithm will need as many iterations as the result has digits and it will need at most 9 iterations (with subtraction) per digit.

Comment: pls take a look at OP. i updated it with new progress.

Comment: @vvsg: How about you print inum_firstCP and inum_second at each iteration before every while check and see what happens?

Comment: Before this do while loop i tried that and everything worked fine. now it loops forever and i can't even see the prints because they appear and disappear too fast.

Comment: @vvsg: Then just stop the program after a second (CTRL+C) and scroll back up as terminals keep history.

Comment: OK. now I know compare function is always returning 1. that's why it goes into an infinite loop. any idea how to fix it??

Comment: @vvsg: You shall not print the result of the compare function, you shall print inum_firstCP and inum_second the line before the while statement, because then you will see what happens to these two and why the compare function always returns 1.

Comment: thanks for advise. turned out firstlen and secondlen were causing problem. i updated the OP. will completely fix the code in the OP ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

@Mecki Try with 54 664 455 645 655 divided by 5 465 126 544, it fails. At step 3 you must add a number of '0' corresponding to the difference of length between the divisor (x n x 10) and the "rest". ie if the rest is 13 190 205 655 (11 digits length) and divisor is 54 651 265 440 000 (14 digits length) then three '0' must be added to the result before performing the next loop.

Comment: I don't think this should be an answer. If you can't post a comment you have to wait to have the required reputation

Comment: @Gianmarco arf! effectively I didn't see I can't post a comment for the moment. Thanks for your remark!